# Firestore Add Custom Objects with Reference Attribute

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been adding POJOs to Firestore that automatically interprets them as JSON objects for the database. However I want to have one of my POJOs have what Firestore calls a **reference** type. Would the attribute type just be `DocumentReference` instead of a `String`?

I'm working on an Android project using Java.

Here is the custom object example from the Firebase Docs.

```java
public class City {

private String name;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    private boolean capital;
    private long population;
    private List<String> regions;

    public City() {}

    public City(String name, String state, String country, boolean capital, long population, List<String> regions) {
        // ...
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public boolean isCapital() {
        return capital;
    }

    public long getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public List<String> getRegions() {
        return regions;
    }

    }
```

Then to add to the database

```java
   City city = new City("Los Angeles", "CA", "USA",
       false, 5000000L, Arrays.asList("west_coast", "sorcal"));
   db.collection("cities").document("LA").set(city);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some simple testing and figured it out.
The attribute type is indeed `DocumentReference` for custom objects when adding directly to Firestore.

Here is an example where the creator of a `Group` is a `reference` to a user in the database:

```java
//Class POJO that holds data
public class Group {
   private String name;
   private DocumentReference creator;

   public Group(){}

   public Group(String name, DocumentReference ref) {
       this.name = name;
       this.creator = ref;
   }

   public String getName() { return this.name; }
   public DocumentReference getCreator() { return this.creator; }

}

// Add to database
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DocumentReference ref = db.collection("users").document(uid);

Group newGroup = new Group("My Group", ref);

db.collection("groups").document().set(newGroup);
```